Best way to implement conditional tabbed routing in vue
What I'm trying to implement is routing with tabs where the available tabs change depending on the user type (upon authentication the user type gets stored in a pinia store).
This is what I ended up implementing:
const mappingAudienceGuard = async (to: RouteLocation): Promise<true | '/mypath'> => {
  const userStore = useUserStore()

  // if user not in memory get user
  if (userStore.user == null) {
    await userStore.getUser()
  }

  if (to.meta.enabledTypes?.includes(userStore.user.type) ?? true) {
    return true
  }

  return '/mypath'
}

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/mypath',
    redirect: () => (isCustom(useUserStore().user) ? '/mypath/orders-custom' : '/mypath/orders'),
    name: 'My Path',
    beforeEnter: authenticationGuard,
    component: DynamicInlineMenu,
    props: {
      links: [
        {
          to: '/mypath/orders',
          text: 'Orders',
          audience: [UserType.STANDARD]
        },
        {
          to: '/mypath/orders-custom',
          text: 'Orders Custom',
          audience: [UserType.CUSTOM]
        }
        // [...]
      ],
      title: 'My Title'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'orders',
        components: { tabContent: OrderListPage },
        beforeEnter: mappingAudienceGuard,
        meta: { enabledTypes: [UserType.STANDARD] }
      },
      {
        path: 'orders-custom',
        components: { tabContent: OrderListCustomPage },
        beforeEnter: mappingAudienceGuard,
        meta: { enabledTypes: [UserType.CUSTOM] }
      }
      // [...]
    ],
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      title: 'My Title'
    }
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

<template>
  <div>
    <TitleBar :title="title" />
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(link, index) in filteredLinks" :key="index">
          <RouterLink
            :to="link.to"
          >
            {{ link.text }}
          </RouterLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <router-view name="tabContent" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const userStore = useUserStore()
const filteredLinks = computed(() =>
  props.links.filter(({ audience }) => audience.includes(userStore.user.type))
)

interface DynamicInlineMenuProps {
  links: Array<{
    to: string
    text: string
    audience: UserType[]
  }>
  title: string
}

const props = defineProps<DynamicInlineMenuProps>()
</script>

Basically we duplicate tabs information inside the props variable of the route, while we already had such information inside the children array.
I have to declare the audience for each tab twice (inside props and inside children) and I have to filter the tabs twice: I have to filter the props inside the template to not render the tab and I have to add a mappingAudienceGuard inside each children to prevent access if the user manually types an url which is not supposed to be available.
Also there is the redirect issue: '/mypath' is supposed to show by default the first allowed path and I have to duplicate (triplicate?) such information inside the redirect getter as well. I would like to have a single source of thuth.
One possible solution to avoid information duplication would be to remove props and extrapolate the links from children:
const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()
const links = router.options.routes.find(({ path }) => path === route.matched[0].path)?.children

but it's cumbersome and I would still need to add redundant fields like to to the meta property. Also I will still have to duplicate information inside the redirect getter. Maybe I could access the children from the redirect getter as well, but this whole solution doesn't look like the proper way to handle such routing pattern anyway.
What do you suggest?

The problem is that keeping it DRY can create more problems than it solves. Then you will find out that the order of tabs should be different from route definitions or there should be special cases like redirects. The list of tabs could be written manually but it could use related route defs in some way. Regardless, it makes sense to force the use of unique route "name" field to navigate to instead of route paths. You can also use it as id to associate tabs with specific routes, this will allow to easily resolve a route by traversing route defs.

I'd suggest to make all guards predicates and move them to "meta" so they could be used by tab component to check if they are allowed. And for navigation they can be accessed as to.meta.myGuards in router.beforeEach

Onestly I think the (DRY) cure is way worse than the problem:
const getAudienceGuard = <T extends string>(
  parentPath: T,
  enabledTypes: UserType[] | undefined
): (() => Promise<true | T>) => {
  return async (): Promise<true | T> => {
    const userStore = useUserStore()

    // if user not in memory get user
    if (userStore.user == null) {
      await userStore.getUser()
    }

    if (enabledTypes?.includes(getUserType(userStore.user)) ?? true) {
      return true
    }

    return parentPath
  }
}

export const filterChildrenByShowInTabAndAccessibility = async (
  children?: RouteRecordRaw[]
): Promise<RouteRecordRaw[]> => {
  return (
    (await children?.reduce<Promise<RouteRecordRaw[]>>(async (acc, cur) => {
      const guardPredicate = cur.meta?.guard == null || (await cur.meta?.guard?.()) === true
      if (cur.meta?.showInTab === true && guardPredicate) {
        return (await acc).concat(cur)
      }
      return await acc
    }, Promise.resolve([]))) ?? []
  )
}

const redirectToFirstAvailableChild = async (
  to: RouteLocationNormalized
): Promise<NavigationGuardReturn> => {
  if (to.matched.length === 1) {
    return (await filterChildrenByShowInTabAndAccessibility(to.matched[0].children))[0] ?? true
  }
  return true
}

[...]
  {
    path: 'mypath',
    name: 'My Path',
    // FIXME: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2729#issuecomment-2204258741
    beforeEnter: [authenticationGuard, redirectToFirstAvailableChild],
    component: DynamicInlineMenu,
    props: { title: 'My Path' } satisfies DynamicInlineMenuProps,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'orders',
        name: 'Mapped orders',
        components: { tabContent: OrderListPage },
        meta: {
          showInTab: true,
          guard: getAudienceGuard('/v2/responsible-sourcing/mapping', [UserType.STANDARD])
        }
      },
[...]

const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()

const filteredLinks = computedAsync(async () => {
  const children = router.options.routes.find(
    ({ path }) => path === route.matched[0].path
  )?.children
  return await filterChildrenByShowInTabAndAccessibility(children)
})

